# is my proof by contradiction correct?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Suppose that n is a positive even integer with $n/2$ being odd. Prove that there do not exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ with $x^2−y^2=n$.

Assume that there exist positive integers positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2-y^2=n$.

then, because $n$ is even, $x$ and $y$ must both be even or $x$ and $y$ must both be odd.

if $x$ and $y$ are both even we obtain $(2k)^2-(2j)^2$.

and therefore, $4(k^2-j^2)=n$.

if we divide by $2$ we get $2(k^2-j^2)=n/2$ where $2(k^2-j^2)$ is even by definition and $n/2$ is odd. We have a contradiction.

if $x$ and $y$ are both odd we obtain $(2k+1)^2-(2j+1)^2$.

and therefore $4k^2+4k+1-(4j^2+4j+1)=4(k^2+k-j^2-j)=n$.

if we divide by $2$ we get $2(k^2+k-j^2-j)=n/2$ where $2(k^2+k-j^2-j)$ is even by definition and $n/2$ is odd. We have a contradiction.

qed

Comment: This looks good.  It would look better with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This is fine. ${} {} {} {} $

Comment: Correct. Good proof

Comment: It's good, it could use $(x+y)-(x-y)=2y$ making the two parentheses the same parity. If they are both even $n$ is a multiple of 4, if both odd $n$ is odd .

Comment: Yep...  That's it.  Squares of even numbers are divisible by $4$ and squares of odd numbers are $1$ more than multiples of $4$.  For $x^2 \pm y^2$ to be even/odd they must be same/different parity.  So $x^2 - y^2$, if $x^2,y^2$ same parity, are $0-0$ or $1-1$ more than a sum of two multiples of $4$